# Change By Name in sharepoint Blog site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery-ui

How can i change the by name in blog site?. I checked that it is redirecting to /_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=17. I can get this id by running the below power shell script. But how can i change it in the blog site with my name. PFA screen shot for the same[image]

```
Get-SPUser -Web http://santoshsite.com/sites/santosh | ForEach-Object{ "" + $_.Id + " " + $_.Name }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar scenario where I had to set specific authors, since you included a powershell code sample here is the powershell I used to make the changes. Be aware this goes through all posts and asks if you want to change the author on each one. It also changes the editor as well.

Please take the time to read the script before using, and be sure to change the web url as well as the domain in the $editoruser variable. I realize this isn't the best script, and could greatly be improved on, but it worked for my purposes.

```
#Set Modified Users
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

##########################################################################
function UpdateAuthorEditor( $spItem, $spWeb, $Author, $Editor)
##########################################################################
{

        if ($Author -and ($Author -ne "SHAREPOINT\system"))
        {
            try
            {
                Write-Host "    Updating Author Field"
                $AuthorUser =$spWeb.Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser("YOURDOMAINHERE\"+$Author)
                $spItem["Author"] = $AuthorUser
            }
            catch
            {
                $e = "Unable to set Author, Can't find user: {0}" -f $Author
                Log $e

                $spItem["Author"] = $spItem["Author"]  
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $spItem["Author"] = $spItem["Author"]  
        }

        if ($Editor -and ($Editor -ne "SHAREPOINT\system"))
        {
            try
            {
                Write-Host "    Updating Editor Field"
                $EditorUser =$spWeb.Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser("YOURDOMAINHERE\"+$Editor)
                $spItem["Editor"] = $EditorUser
            }
            catch
            {
                $e = "Unable to set Author, Can't find user: {0}" -f $Editor
                Log $e

                $spItem["Editor"] = $spItem["Editor"]  
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $spItem["Editor"] = $spItem["Editor"]  
        }

}

$web = Get-SPWeb "ENTER SPWEB URL HERE"
$list = $web.Lists["Posts"]

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
    $updateitem = Read-Host "Do you want to update $($item.Title)? Y or N"
    if ($updateitem -eq "Y")
    {

        $userID = Read-Host "Enter Login"

        UpdateAuthorEditor $item $web $userID $userID

        $item.SystemUpdate()
    }
}

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Excellent this works for me Perfectly :-)... A ton thanks to Blue bird

Answer (score 0):

The initial blog post is set as the system account, all subsequent posts will show as the person who creates the post. Simply delete the initial blog post if it isn't necessary.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. What if i want to change any other name . My scenario was the blog site was published by some XXXX person so i want my name there instead of his name.is there any way to do the same ?

Comment: I think you'd have to get a reference on the item in the Posts list and try updating the created by field, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/03/14/can-we-update-the-values-of-created-by-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists.aspx